# What way is best to enter data into a HTML table using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have got this table:

```
        <div id="customer-content">
            <table>
                <caption>Customer Details</caption>
                <tr>
                    <th>Customer no</th>
                    <td>customer-no</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alt">
                    <th>First name</th>
                    <td>first-name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Last name</th>
                    <td>last-name</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="alt">
                    <th>Phone number</th>
                    <td>phone-number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date of birth</th>
                    <td>dob</td>
                </tr>                   
            </table>
        </div>
```

what is the best way to enter some data into it via jQuery:

```
    $('div#customer-content table tr td').text( '1234' );
```

The above is ok for customer-no but how do I do the rest ??

Comment: that would set all td's text to 1234

Comment: How would I then target each <td> individually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way of doing this could be like this:-

```
$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(0).text( '1234' );
```

This would enter 1234 into the first cell in the row (we use zero as the first item in the array in javascript).  To enter into the second, you would use:-

```
$('div#customer-content table tr td').eq(1).text( '1234' );
```

And so on, increasing the value in the eq selector as you go.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eQ6KC/)

Answer (score 2):

```
var texts = ['text1','text2','text3',...];
var i = 0;
$('div#customer-content table tr td').each(function(){$(this).text( text[i] );i++;};
```

Comment: thanks for the help, but I am not trying to set 1234 to every td cell but individually. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Ok i added the code that you can use generaly if you have n elements and not adding them one by one